# How to create/display an icon in windows taskbar when application is running in Java (NOT in System tray)?

Tags: java, windows, icons, taskbar

[image]

Please tell me how to create/display an icon in windows task bar when application is running in Java? I can only find the solutions for System Tray. As shown in the image, I want icon on task bar.

Comment: Those icons correspond to windows. You create them like any other application does: by creating a window.